# Reading credentials from one file into another

Tags: python

I have one py file where I want to call credentials of different accounts on the user choice,
I have the below `Creds.json` file with credentials as below:

```
'Account1':{
        "client_token" : "12345678",
        "client_secret" : "9865432",
        "access_token": "3459865"
 
}
'Account2':{
        "client_token" : "33456787",
        "client_secret" : "23456787",
        "access_token": "98654378"
 
}

'Account3':{
        "client_token" : "1234567",
        "client_secret" : "87654378",
        "access_token": "35627826"
 
}
```

I have a `main.py` file where if the user inputs 1, 2 or 3 those credentials from the creds.json file will be used,

```
choice = input("Which account credentials do you want to use: ")
   print("Press 1 for Account 1")
   print("Press 2 for Account 2")
   print("Press 3 for Account 3")
```

when 1 is present I want the credentials under Account1 and when 2 is the choice credentials under Account2 should be imported here in the `main.py` file for use.

Please help me, how can I do it, I got confused when I tried it out, Do I need to change the Creds.json file to a py file or any other way, please provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load you credentials into a dict with:

```
import json
path = "Creds.json"
file = open(path)
content= file.read()
credentials = json.loads(content)
```

Then you have your input:

```
choice = input("Which account credentials do you want to use: ")
print("Press 1 for Account 1")
print("Press 2 for Account 2")
print("Press 3 for Account 3")
```

And finally gather your crendential with:

```
credential = credentials["Account{0}".format(int(choice))]
```

You have to correct your file `Creds.json`:

```
{
    "Account1":{
        "client_token" : "12345678",
        "client_secret" : "9865432",
        "access_token": "3459865"
    },
    "Account2":{
        "client_token" : "33456787",
        "client_secret" : "23456787",
        "access_token": "98654378"
    },
    "Account3":{
        "client_token" : "1234567",
        "client_secret" : "87654378",
        "access_token": "35627826"
    }
}
```

You can correct you Cred.json with this script:

```
content = open("Creds.json").read()
content = content.replace("'", '"')
content = content.replace("}\n", '},')
content = "{" + content + "}"
credentials = json.loads(content)
```

And here in production version

```
import json
credentials = json.loads("{" + open("Creds.json").read().replace("'", '"').replace("}\n", '},') + "}")
while True:
    choice = input("Which account credentials do you want to use:" + "".join("\nPress {0} for {0}".format(i + 1, credential) for i, credential in enumerate(credentials))+"\n")
    key = "Account{0}".format(int(choice))
    if key in credentials:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong answer, please retry (CRTC + C to exit)")
credential = credentials[key]
print(credential)
```

Comment: The dictionary will work, however, it does not account for the user entering an invalid selection.

Comment: Thx @JacobBlomquist, corrected in last code block

Comment: @VincentBénet First of all thank you both for the quick response both answers are amazing and work for me. Can you please help me understand in here credential = credentials["Account{0}".format(int(choice))], what does Account{0} do, it takes the choice user takes, but how automatically?, please help me understand -

Comment: "Account{0}".format(int(choice)) take the user choice if it is in json and create the corresponding key for the dictionnary. Note it work only because you named "AccountN" your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very quick and dirty example. First of all, I edited your json file to be a full JSON object:

`Creds.json:`

```json
{
  "Account1": {
    "client_token": "12345678",
    "client_secret": "9865432",
    "access_token": "3459865"
  },
  "Account2": {
    "client_token": "33456787",
    "client_secret": "23456787",
    "access_token": "98654378"
  },

  "Account3": {
    "client_token": "1234567",
    "client_secret": "87654378",
    "access_token": "35627826"
  }
}
```

Here is some python code for reading this file and selecting an account based on a selection.

`main.py`

```py
import json

def main():
    credFile = open('Creds.json')
    creds = json.load(credFile)
    
    print("Press 1 for Account 1")
    print("Press 2 for Account 2")
    print("Press 3 for Account 3")
    choice = input("Which account credentials do you want to use: ")
    
    chosenCreds = ""

    if choice=="1":
        chosenCreds=creds["Account1"]
    elif choice=="2":
        chosenCreds=creds["Account2"]
    elif choice=="3":
        chosenCreds=creds["Account3"]
    else:
        print("Invalid Selection!")
        return

    # Your code here using "Chosen Creds"...
    print(chosenCreds)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```